# Need Google App script for deleting rows from a spreadsheet automatically after every few days

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking for a way to delete outdated rows from a google spreadsheet automatically after every few days. I have timestamps stored for every row in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt the clean up function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17078362/1677912), and make it run as a timed trigger.